# Why are Pytorch transform functions not being differentiated with autograd?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have been trying to write a set of transforms on input data. I also need the transforms to be differentiable to compute the gradients. However, gradients do not seem to be calculated for the resize, normalize transforms.

```
from torchvision import transforms

from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

resize = transforms.Resize(size=224, interpolation=transforms.InterpolationMode.BICUBIC, max_size=None, antialias=None)

crop = transforms.CenterCrop(size=(224, 224))

normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.48145466, 0.4578275, 0.40821073), std=(0.26862954, 0.26130258, 0.27577711))

img = torch.Tensor(images[30])

img.requires_grad = True

rgb = torch.dsplit(torch.Tensor(img),3)

transformed = torch.stack(rgb).reshape(3,100,100)

resized = resize.forward(transformed)

normalized = normalize.forward(resized)

image_features = clip_model.encode_image(normalized.unsqueeze(0).to(device))

text_features = clip_model.encode_text(text_inputs)

similarity = (100.0 * image_features @ text_features.T).softmax(dim=-1)
```

When running `normalized.backward()`, there are no gradients for resized and transformed.

I have tried to find the gradient for each individual transform, but it still does not calculate the gradients.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to reproduce your error, what I get when backpropagating the gradient from `normalized` is:

> RuntimeError: `grad` can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs

What this error means is that the tensor you are calling `backward` onto should be a scalar and not a vector or multi-dimensional tensor. Generally you would want to reduce the dimensionality for example by averaging or summing. For example you could do the following:

```
> normalized.mean().backward()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the transforms themselves: many of them did not affect the gradients as they were rearrangements or transposes of the original tensor.